# Issue with slick.js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

So I'm using slick library for the first time in order to get my slider working, however I'm running into various issues:

1) My first slider contents are not being rendered for some reason, only the background is visible.

2)When fading out the sliders are "stacking" to the right side of the slider container instead of completely dissapearing.

```js
$('.slider_zim_items_container').slick({
 
  autoplay: true,
  dots:false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite:true, 
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 2000,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
}).slick('slickFilter', '.slide');
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
/*SLIDER ZIM START*/
.slider_zim_maincontainer{width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; overflow:hidden; display:flex; flex-direction:column; ;}
.slider_zim_prev{position:absolute; width:60px; height:50px;  top:50%; border-radius:0px; transform:translateY(-50%); left:0px; z-index:9999; display:none; background-color:rgb(240,240,240);}
.slider_zim_next{position:absolute; width:60px; height:50px; top:50%; border-radius:0px; transform:translateY(-50%); right:0px; z-index:9999; display:none; background-color:rgb(240,240,240);}
.slider_zim_prev .fa{font-size:32px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); margin:auto; padding-right:5px;}
.slider_zim_next .fa{font-size:32px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); margin:auto; padding-left:5px;}
.slider_zim_navigation_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:none; border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;  position:absolute; padding:10px; background-color:none; bottom:25px; right:25px; z-index:9999;}
.slider_zim_items_container{width:100%; height:100vh; position:relative; overflow:hidden; background-color:black;}


.slider_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.slider_top_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:50px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:99999; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.slider_bottom_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:20px; position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)); z-index:9999;}
.slider_left_gradient_overlay{width:50px; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:99999; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.slider_right_gradient_overlay{width:50px; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; z-index:99999; background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.





.slider_zim_small_container{width:100%; height:10vh; background-color:rgb(240,240,240); display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 25px;}
.slider_zim_small_text{font-size:18px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); font-weight:600; margin-left:auto; margin-right:10px;}
.slider_zim_small_social_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex;}
.slider_zim_small_social_icon{width:40px; height:40px; display:flex; border-radius:4px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin:0px 10px;}
.slider_zim_small_social_icon .fab{margin:auto; font-size:29px; color:white;}
.prev{transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0;}
.next{transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0;}
.container:hover .prev{opacity:1;}
.container:hover .next{opacity:1;}
.slider_active{display:flex; opacity:1;}
.slider_active_dot{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
.dot{width:15px; height:15px;  border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); transition: all 800ms ease; margin:0px 15px; cursor:pointer;}
/*SLIDER ZIM END*/



/**/
.slider_item_container{width:100%; height:100%; padding:75px; position:relative; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
.slider_item_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:3; top:0px; left:0px; }
.slider_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:2; top:0px; left:0px; background-cover:size; }
.slider_item_title{font-size:45px; color:var(--web_primary_color); font-family:Yesteryear; z-index:9999; margin:20px 0px;}
.slider_item_info_container{width:75%; min-height:60%; margin:20px 0px; border-radius:4px; z-index:9999999; display:flex; justify-content:center;}
.slider_item_info_subcontainer{width:75%; height:100%; display:flex;}
.slider_item_info_column_container{width:50%; height:100%; padding:15px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center; }
.slider_item_info_row_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; margin:15px 0px;}
.slider_item_info_row_icon_title_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:flex-end; margin-bottom:15px;}
.slider_item_info_row_icon_title_container .fa{font-size:24px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); margin-right:10px;}
.slider_item_info_row_icon_title{font-size:30px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); }
.slider_item_info_row_link{font-size:14px; color:var(--web_primary_color); align-self:flex-end;}
.slider_item_info_row_sche_container{width:auto; height:auto; margin:15px 0px; display:flex; flex-direction:row; align-items:center;}
.slider_item_info_row_sche_container .fa{font-size:24px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); margin-right:10px;}
.slider_item_info_row_sche_title{font-size:30px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); }
.slider_item_info_column_sche_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; }
.slider_item_info_column_sche_data_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:center; margin:3px 0px;}
.slider_item_info_column_sche_data_day{font-size:14px; color:var(--web_primary_color); margin-right:5px;}
.slider_item_info_column_sche_data_hour{font-size:14px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
.slider_item_info_column_sche_data_separator{color:var(--web_primary_color); font-size:4px; margin:0px 10px;}
.slider_item_links_container{width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; z-index:99999; margin:20px 0px;}
.slider_item_link{padding:12px 17px; background-color:var(--web_primary_color); font-size:18px; color:white; margin:0px 15px;}
/**/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider_zim_maincontainer" style="">
 <div class="slider_zim_items_container" style="">
  <div class="slider_item_container slide" style="">
      <div class="slider_item_gradient_overlay" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);" ></div>
      <div class="slider_item_image" style="background-color:pink;"></div>
      <span class="slider_item_title" style="">{{ $config['web_name']['value'] }}</span>
      <div class="slider_item_info_container" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
       <div class="slider_item_info_subcontainer" style="">
        <div class="slider_item_info_column_container" style="">
         <div class="slider_item_info_row_container" style="">
          <div class="slider_item_info_row_icon_title_container" style="">
           <i class="fa fa-phone" style=""></i>
           <span class="slider_item_info_row_icon_title" style="">Reservar</span>
       </div>
       <a class="slider_item_info_row_link" href="" style="">{{ $config['booking_phone']['value'] }}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slider_item_info_row_container" style="">
          <div class="slider_item_info_row_icon_title_container" style="">
           <i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt" style=""></i>
           <span class="slider_item_info_row_icon_title" style="">Visitanos</span>
       </div>
       <a class="slider_item_info_row_text" href="" style="font-size:14px; color:var(--web_primary_color);  align-self:flex-end;">{{ $config['full_address']['value'] }}</a>
       <a class="slider_item_info_row_text" href="" style="font-size:14px; color:var(--web_primary_color); align-self:flex-end;">{{ $config['city_zip_address']['value'] }}</a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="slider_item_info_column_container" style="">
         <div class="slider_item_info_row_sche_container" style="">
       <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt" style=""></i>
       <span class="slider_item_info_row_sche_title" style="">Horario</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slider_item_info_column_sche_container" style="">
          @foreach($schedules as $schedule)
       <div class="slider_item_info_column_sche_data_container" style="">
           <span class="slider_item_info_column_sche_data_day" style="">{{ $schedule->day }}:</span>
        <span class="slider_item_info_column_sche_data_hour" style="">{{ $schedule->first }}</span>
        <i class="slider_item_info_column_sche_data_separator fa fa-circle" style=""></i>
        <span class="slider_item_info_column_sche_data_hour" style="">{{ $schedule->second }}</span>
       </div>
       @endforeach
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider_item_links_container" style="">
       <a class="slider_item_link" href="" style="">VER NUESTRO MENU</a>
       <a class="slider_item_link" href="" style="">HACER UNA RESERVA</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red; position:relative; "></div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:yellow; position:relative; "></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, I get the impression you copy pasted a bunch of HTML and CSS into your project which you're not really sure of what it is doing.

I do see a loop, are those values filled properly?
`@foreach($schedules as $schedule)`

What about the styles/vars in HTML?
`style="font-size:14px; color:var(--web_primary_color);  align-self:flex-end;">{{ $config['full_address']['value'] }}`

Seeing this and looking at your questions My guess would be.

1. A `div` is misplaced/not rendered, or your CSS is broken preventing sections from showing up properly.
2. Again could be a mistake in your CSS or HTML container structure.

If you haven't already, I'd suggest reading up on the docs of [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick) and create a slider from the ground up. This way you feel comfortable about your code and styles and what it is doing. From there you can build things up and move your slider into your project.

The basic html structure

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/flower"></div>
  <div class="slider"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/cat"></div>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript to load slick.js once the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel-wrapper').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  });
});
```

You can use [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/roycode/pen/BPzRmK) as a starting point and tweak it to your liking.

Hope this helps.